# R stringr::string_replace_all() with named vector problem

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, str-replace, stringr

I'm having trouble standardizing addresses for a merge. USPS has a big list of standard abbreviations which I turned into a named vector. When I run `str_replace_all()` as shown it does not replace `'AVENUE'` variations as I hoped it would. I believe it grabs the first match instead of the longest or exact match, but I can't think of an elegant way to fix this. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
library(tidyverse)

addresses = c("10580 BAR AVE", "1234 WILL AVENUE")

standard_abbreviations <- c('AV' = 'AVE', 'AVE' = 'AVE', 'AVENU' = 'AVE', 'AVENUE' = 'AVE', 'AVN' = 'AVE')

addresses_standardized <- str_replace_all(addresses, standard_abbreviations)
```

Incorrect Result with avenue variations misspelled:

```
> addresses_standardized
[1] "10580 BAR AVEE"    "1234 WILL AVEENUE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly applying your replacements, try:

```r
library(tidyverse)

addresses = c("10580 BAR AVE", "1234 WILL AVENUE")

standard_abbreviations <- c('AV\\b' = 'AVE', 'AVE' = 'AVE', 'AVENU\\b' = 'AVE', 'AVENUE' = 'AVE', 'AVN\\b' = 'AVE')

addresses_standardized <- str_replace_all(addresses, standard_abbreviations)
addresses_standardized
#> [1] "10580 BAR AVE" "1234 WILL AVE"
```

`\\b` is for `\b` which is regular expression for end of word.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html